# Call mysql DB from nginx conf file

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Currently I'm doing reverse proxy via harcoded URLs in nginx.conf file itself. nginx is deployed over kubernetes using docker.

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location /mysite {
        if ($arg_i = 45) {
                 return 301 https://www.youtube.com;
            }
}
```

I want to connect to mysql and fetch the URL value directly from a table during runtime.
Please share how to connect to cloud SQL (mysql) instance in nginx.conf

Comment: This question makes no sense

Comment: The problem is that if you rewrite that file, the configuration needs to be reloaded, so you need to restart nginx in every request...

Comment: I want to avoid URL hardcoding and make it dynamic using DB table. That conf file will be written once and from next time, URL will be fetched from DB table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an answer to your question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49729/how-to-query-mysql-to-build-nginx-configuration-file), which suggests using a NginX module . This is unsupported and untested, but can help you get started as there are no included/prebuilt methods to do this.